# How to allow camera to be launched in secure mode (without gallery icon) programmatically?

Tags: android, camera

I was trying to implement the quick camera myself and was unable to either unlock the screen or launch the camera in secure mode. Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I haven't done the camera part yet,but the accelerometer part is inspired from [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/sensor/android-accelerometer-example/)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem using a separate intent for secure camera and lunching it when the screen is locked i.e keyguard.

```
 if(kgMgr.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()){
     Intent secure_camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE);
     secure_camera_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
     this.startActivity(secure_camera_intent);
}
```